# Failed Installation of Docker plugin for Intellij Idea CE 2016.1 due to <required plugin "org.jetbrains.plugins.remote-run" not installed.>

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, docker, dockerfile

After upgrading Intellij Idea to version 2016.1 I got problem with Docker plugin due to missed dependency **org.jetbrains.plugins.remote-run**

> Plugin Error
>               Problems found loading plugins:
>               Plugin "Docker integration" was not loaded: required plugin "org.jetbrains.plugins.remote-run" not installed.
>               Disable Docker integration
>               Open plugin manager

Do you any ideas where I can find this plugin ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-153214), One of the guys developing IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1 thought that the remote-run plugin was available in the Community Edition for IntelliJ IDEA (which it isn't). That was this morning (Dated: 18th March 2016), hopefully he'll extract the dependency sometime soon and update the plugin.

TL;DR: Wait a little while until the Docker plugin has been updated, a Jetbrains Developer screwed up.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [changelog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/03/intellij-idea-2016-1-is-here/) the

> The Docker plugin has been improved in many ways

**Reinstall** it to assure missing dependencies are provided.

Comment: thank you for answer , but, unfortunately ,  re-installation of docker plugin doesn't work for me. I guess it could be Community Edition problem

Comment: Please add the information about the Community Edition to your question.